# Create a nag alert (update available!) checker script

Tags: php

I have a remote updater script that resides in my wordpress theme folder. The script simply calls out to the central server and grabs a zip file which contains the latest updated files for the theme.

I'd like to enable a nag alert checker that executes whenever the theme's options panel is accessed and I'm just brainstorming it here for a sanity check.

The nag checker would simply look out on my central server and read the contents of a text file which contains the current version number (a 4 digit integer, 0001, 0002, etc and that's it).

If the 4 digit number contained in the text file is greater than the version number stored in the theme's version variable, then it would display a nag alert for the user so that they can execute the update script to retrieve the update.

Am I on the right track? Are there better ways to do this that are easier to implement? I suppose I could check a date stamp on the local update file and compare it to the update file on the server as well. Not sure which is best or easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds good to me.  You can use `file_get_contents()` on the local and remote files (containing the version numbers), use `intval()` on those, and then make the comparison.  If `file_get_contents()` doesn't work on the remove url, then you'll have to use cURL.

Comment: Thanks Jonah, because of the way my update works (it leaves a copy the updater.zip in the target directory) it seems it might be simpler just to do a date comparison between that file and the one on my server. Would that work?

Comment: Right.  That's what I meant, but apparently I wasn't clear enough.  :)